# Kill Hung COM launched Process

Tags: c++, com, automation, ms-office, kill

I have some legacy code that launches Word (and other applications) from a C++ program using COM automation and the MSO dll.  This runs on a server, non-interactively.
Occasionally the application will hang and eventually over many day/weeks, the resources on the server will be used up by many hung processes.

The process is launched:

```
Word::_ApplicationPtr wordApp
HRESULT hr = wordApp.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Word::Application));
```

various calls are then made via the wordApp pointer, one of which may hang.  The code never returns form the call and the C++ code is stalled.

What is a solution to checking for these hangs and then killing off Word?

I have pondered using CreateProcess and using waitforsingleobject with a timeout but I cant then manipulate the object via automation.

I cant see a way of retrieving the handle to the COM launched app so cant kill it using that.

I thought about a separate thread and waiting on that then killing the thread after a timeout but killing a thread doesnt release all the resources i.e. word.

I thought about enumming all the active processes and searching for "winword" then killing every process that matched but this seems messy and a hack.

So anyone any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: This is one core reason that Microsoft very strongly recommends to never run an Office app on a server.  There is no "clean" workaround for it, COM normally garbage-collects zombie processes without a client but that does not work for Office apps from some unfathomable reason.  Using the OpenXML api is the proper way to do it.  Never welcome advice, using a little helper app that can detect and kill zombies is about as "clean" as it gets.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I wonder is there widely available information on how to detect zombie processes?

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to get a window handle for that instance, then enumerate all windows and find the process id?

Comment: if there is sharptooth, I am unaware of how to do it.